# Extract value from struct that meet condition

Tags: swift

I have a struct for different animals, and values for these animals. Im adding animals to it.

```
struct Animal {
var type: String
var weight: String
var cost: String
}

var animals = [Animal]()

func addAnimal(type: String, weight: String, cost: String){
    animals.append(Animal(type: type, weight: weight, cost: cost))
}


addAnimal("monkey", "80", "300")
addAnimal("zebra", "200", "500")
addAnimal("monkey", "50", "250")
```

I want to say, `if type == "monkey"` then return all weights for monkeys. In this example I would want the code to return values "80" and "50".

I'm new to coding so any advice on this would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine filter and map to accomplish what you want as follow:

```
let monkeysWeights = animals.filter{$0.type == "monkey"}.map{$0.weight}

println(monkeysWeights)  // ["80", "50"]
```